# How to pass clicked map marker details?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am tying to pass clicked map marker details from database but still unsuccessfully.
App gets all markers from database and onMarkerClickListener works fine with every marker but after clicking on every map marker I would like to get individual details from database to appear on new activity.

```
new RetrieveTask().execute();

 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, PlaceInfoActivity.class);
```

Should I add some code here eg. putExtra etc.?
                startActivity(intent);

```
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Some parts of the class to get markers from database

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("placename", c.getString("placename"));
                map.put("place", c.getString("place"));
                map.put("lat", c.getString("lat"));
                map.put("lng", c.getString("lng"));
                location.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (location != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < location.size(); i++) {
                placename = location.get(i).get("placename").toString();
                place = location.get(i).get("place").toString();
                lat = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("lat"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("lng"));
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(placename);
                if (Objects.equals(place, ...

mMap.addMarker(marker);
            }
```

I tried many ways but it didn't work.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254665/how-to-get-id-of-marker-clicked-in-google-map-inside-setoninfowindowclicklistene/43254783#43254783

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot.